# TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'statusKnown' of object '#<Object>'

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to update a state based on my props in my react Class based component but i am getting an error

> TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'statusKnown' of object
>   '#'

here is the code below

```
componentDidMount(){
    this.calClass()
  }

calClass = () => {
    console.log(this.props.statusKnown, this.state.active);
    if (this.props.statusKnown == "deactive") this.setState({ active: false });
    else if ((this.props.statusKnown = "active")) this.setState({ active: true });
  };
```

and then in parent component

```
<Button item={item} categoryID={categoryID} statusKnown={status}/>;
```

If react doesn't allow this thing, then what is the possible solution for this ?

Comment: Could you accept my answer, if that was the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed some `=` signs. You should always use `===`

```
componentDidMount(){
    this.calClass()
}

calClass = () => {
    console.log(this.props.statusKnown, this.state.active);
    if (this.props.statusKnown === "deactive") this.setState({ active: false });
    else if ((this.props.statusKnown === "active")) this.setState({ active: true });
};
```